# Xampp's equivalent to "C:/wamp/bin/mysql"?

Tags: mysql, cmd, xampp

I downloaded xampp and need to find xampp's equivalent to "C:/wamp/bin/mysql" in cmd. Im going to be entering it into cmd to set a password.

Comment: Where did you installed XAMPP? And did you installed it on a Windows machine, because you used forward slashes instead of backward slashes?

Comment: You should delete your other duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP's way to mysql (even if currently it is counted as MariaDB, since version I don't exactly know) is:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin
```

There you may find all executable (exe) file you need, it means even mysql.exe - or else.

Of course, name of disk drive may be different, if you have XAMPP installed elsewhere. I had installed (on old computer) on disk drive E, for example.